# Turn off the Ctrl + trackpad zoom function

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + mouse wheel on browser or application windows it zooms in!

Have looked through synclient and inputx but can't figure out how to switch this very annoying feature off. Running ubuntu on ibm lenovo t440s!

Comment: This is application-wide, does not depend on the system. You should look into each application how to disable it.